# Is it possible to change the zoom speed in osmdroid?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

Okay so i am trying to reduce the speed of zoom in osmdroid. Currently the using the function

```
setzoom(int zoomlevel)
```

the zoom speed is set at 500 milliseconds. Is it possible to increase the speed so that i can get an effect of a gradual zoom towards the marker?

Comment: What do you mean with open street maps? Which library do you use?

Comment: This one https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid and this one also https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack

Comment: I don't think there is a way to specify a duration yet, so you may open an issue/feature request there https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues

Answer (score 0):

[Current source code of osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/315b532aea5712e032d261f1d66e23b43c79ce5a/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/MapController.java#L379) still uses static final variable ANIMATION_DURATION_SHORT. Value is located in [MapViewConstants](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/util/constants/MapViewConstants.java) class.

You can fork the library and than build your own version with changed value. You can change the value [using java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection#3301720). But I would not recommend any of those solutions.